# Валидация в сафари

Tags: javascript

Функция валидации полей ввода.

```
function validateValue() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            var regex = new RegExp(/^\d{1,}((\.|,)\d{1,4})?$/);
            var regexNoLetters = /[a-zA-Zа-я-А-Я]/g;
            var re = /^(\d{1,5}[.,]\d{4})[\s\S]*/;

            ctrl.$validators.validateAmount = function(value) {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (value) {

                    var value = value.toString().replace(regexNoLetters, '').replace(',', '.');
                    var result = value.replace(re, '$1');

                    ctrl.$setValidity('amount', true);
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(result);
                    if (!regex.test(result)) {
                        ctrl.$setTouched();
                    }
                    ctrl.$render();
                    return !value ? true : regex.test(result);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

в хроме и аналогичных браузерах все работает нормально. Проблема в сафари. Нет возможности поставить "." то есть дробное число. Не могу понять в чем проблема.
При чем в сафари на маке 17" нормально все. а на 13" проблема. Знаю что на 13" бывают и другие приколы. может кто знает в чем проблема с ними?
Вообще обнаружил что в сафари делает все наоборот. Вместо того что бы блокировать все лишние символы "," заменять на "." Получается что ". и ," блокируються а остальные символы и буквы вводить можно. Что не так?

Comment: Ошибки/предупреждения в консоли браузера есть?

Comment: никаких ошибок и предупреждений. прошу прощения. одна строка была не верной. сейчас поправил. посмотрите еще раз. а то был тестовый код.   var regex = new RegExp(/^\d{1,}((\.|,)\d{1,4})?$/);

Comment: еще момент интересный. после 0 "." ставится. после любой другой цифры нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция рабочая. Но. Проблемой оказалось то что в инпуте тип стоял number, для работы валидатора необходимо текстовый тип поля.

```
<input type="text">
```

Comment: input - незакрывающий тег

Comment: Получается, что в Сафари был не баг, а фича?

Comment: получается так))